# How to lock a Windows client in Synergy with a Mac Server

Tags: macos, windows-10, synergy

I have my Mac as my server and my Windows 10 machine as a client. I want to be able to do a Win+L to lock Windows from my Mac keyboard using Command+L. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac OS (server) side, go into server configuration and the "Screen and Links" tab. Make sure that your WIndows PC is showing and double click its icon. Under Modifier keys, set them to this:

- Shift -> Shift
- Ctrl -> Super
- Alt -> Alt
- Meta -> Meta
- Super -> Ctrl

I have this setup and it works perfectly on my PC.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just makes my control key act like the Windows key. Did you create a Hotkey for it?

Comment: What about the Elevate field? I have mine set to Always. Do you use SSL Encryption?

Comment: I do use SSL. Not sure how or if that would have any impact. 

I have the setup above working to send to my Linux laptop (at work) from my Mac. All the Windows key combos work fine. I do have a Windows keyboard connected to my Mac, so I'm literally using the Windows key when doing things on my Mac. Something in Hotkeys might help, but that's a feature I've never played with,.

Comment: I'd rather not have to use a windows keyboard, I prefer the mac keyboard. But, my SSL Encryption option is greyed out on both the server and client. I'll have to get that working before I can try to see if that would resolve the issue. Thanks for your help!